# How to launch other Android App from Android App?

Tags: android, android-intent

How to launch other Android App from Android App if I have got the package name of App?

For example: I create a `Button` in an **Android App**. When press the Button , the Skype will launch.

1. Is it possible to do the above action in Android?
2. Is it should use Intent to launch other App when Button has been click?
3. What permission does it need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Comment: in the upper right corner of this page you will find a white input field. You know...this is used for searching purposes,

Comment: @Martin, did any of the answers work? Facing any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not your app, as you mentioned, "Skype". You can use the app's package ID in intent.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

For **Skype**, it becomes,

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

In your Java file, say **MainActivity.java**

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
    startActivity(launchIntent);
                }
            });
```

And in layout file, say **activity_main.xml**

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Skype →"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Yes if You have other app package name

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("other app package name");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to launch skype or any other app:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("<skype_package_name>");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
try {
    if (pm.getApplicationInfo("com.your.package.name", 0) == null) {
        // no talk, no update
        Toast.makeText(context, "packagenot found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Intent packageIntent= pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.your.package.name");

        packageIntent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        packageIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(packageIntent);
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    // no talk, no update
    Toast.makeText(context, "Package not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final String appPackageName = "com.example";
                        final Intent openPlayStore = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
                        if (hasHandlerForIntent(openPlayStore))
                            startActivity(openPlayStore);
                        else
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));

private boolean hasHandlerForIntent(Intent intent) {
        return getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0;
    }
```